# Wireless connection problems

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have connected to the device I'm working on with ssh:

```
   uname -a
```

Result:

```
    Linux am37x-evm 2.6.37 #1 Thu Nov 10 11:53:10 HKT 2016 armv71 GNU/Linux
```

The device runs an application on boot which can be used to select the wireless network then get an IP from DHCP.

The problem I'm having is that after a short time the wireless connection is lost.  Is there anything I can do to keep the connection alive?

I've tried from the ssh session:

```
    ping 8.8.8.8
```

This seems to keep the connection alive.  I search online for a solution but it seems the distribution of Linux on the target doesn't have much.

Comment: What's the router model?  The model of the wireless adapter wouldn't hurt either. The dropped connection problem could easily be interference

Comment: Product name: MediaAccess TG589vac v2, Software Version 17.2, Firmware Version: 17.2.0361-0901023-20180530170603

Comment: Have you tried changing the channel on the router? Try 1,6, and 11 while monitoring for drop outs. Does it make a difference if you hard reboot it? (Removing power for 10-15 secs) let me know if either of those change the problem pattern.

Comment: I now have a firmware update for the device I'm having a problem with, the manufacturer obviously found the problem.

Comment: Trying just created another post...now I can't format the MicroSD card that I need to put the firmware update onto.

Comment: I don't have a PC anymore all apple stuff...which is usually great...not this time

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-use-disk-utility-3634604/%3famp

Comment: I'm afraid this is where my expertise ends... :/ I'm not a Mac user. I hope that I pointed you in the right direction though. Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the device and having contacted the manufacturer a firmware upgrade was supplied.  This was uploaded and the unit soak tested.

I’m pleased to say no more problem.

Comment: Cool, it may help to let other users know the firmware version number that fixed the dropout issue. +1